# Best way to have DEV, TEST, PROD environments in one Django project

Tags: django

I have a Django project that is deployed to a `dev`, `test`, and `prod` website online.

In the `prod` version, it needs to **connect to a db**, so I need to have some kind of if statement to determine if it is running at the `prod url` and then if so, connect the db.

What is the best way to achieve something like this? *Should I even use if statements or is there a better way to do it?* Thanks!!

Comment: Why not make three (similar) `settings.py` filesx that are each used for one of the environments?

Comment: So one for each environment? How would I determine which environment I am in and then set the ```settings.py``` acordingly?

Comment: You run different settings in different envs, manually, since it has only three conditions

Comment: @minglyu what do you mean by manually? Do I have to change it every time my environment changes? Thanks!!